# Hyperlink is not working in ckeditor when clicking it is not navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How to navigate link in editor i have provided link

```
<p>Hai welcome <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">click me</a></p>
```

when i click on 'click me' in editor it is not navigating

Comment: Why would it if it is in an editor?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your markup.

The answer is simply that in some editing environments, the link will not behave normally.

The **StackOverflow** editing environment is another example where the link does not behave normally (even though the markup is completely valid).

**Working Example:**

```html
<p>Hi. Welcome. <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Click Me</a>.</p>
```